# QComboBox activated(int)

Tags: c++, qt

I'm using qt 5.2. My connect function's call:

```
QObject::connect(ui->mycombobox, SIGNAL(activated(0)), ui->mypushbutton, SLOT(toggle()));
// When I select first element from mycombobox, mypushbutton must be disabled
```

Program prints:

```
QObject::connect: No such signal QComboBox::activated(0) in <myfile>
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? You can't pass an int as a parameter to connect (there you can only specify types), so if you want help you need to tell us what you want to do, and it never hurs to read about signals and slots in the documentation: https://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/signalsandslots.html

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Signal which you try to use is activated(int), i have no idea why you are trying to connect activated(0). It should be like this:

```
QObject::connect(ui->mycombobox, SIGNAL(activated(int)), ui->mypushbutton, SLOT(toggle()));
```

If you want to filter action using item index, you should pass argument to your slot and there perform specific action for e.g.:

```
QObject::connect(ui->mycombobox, SIGNAL(activated(int)), this, SLOT(mySlot(int)));
/*...*/
void MyClass::mySlot(int arg)
{
    if(arg == 0)
          ui->mypushbutton.toggle();
}
```